# How to check convergence of $\int^2_0\ln x\, dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Given the integral $$\int^2_0\ln x\, dx$$
I need to check it's convergence. How I proceeded: 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\int^2_{0+\epsilon}\ln x \,dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}2\left((\ln 2-1)-\epsilon(\ln \epsilon-1)\right).$$
But I'm confused on how to proceed after this. Please help.

Comment: Use that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\ln x=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\dfrac{\ln x}{\dfrac 1x}.$ Apply L'Hôpital to get $0.$

Comment: It's a standard limit from high school!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. You are on the right track. Note that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\ln(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}=-\lim_{x\to 0^+} x=0.$$
where we used Hopital's rule.